# Android SDK FingerPaint example

Tags: android, sdk

I hava a simple question about Android FingerPaint example: [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)
(Websited is updated, my question is regarding old version as explained below)

On of the first things it does is

`setContentView(new MyView(this));`

In MyView constructor: (website is updated but when I loaded my Sample from my SDK it was this way, my question is about this code)

```
    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c); 
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }
```

This basically makes bitmap of 320 x 480, but when I run this code on my tablet or high-res phone, I noticed that it would scale the bitmap, making the paint object appropriately bigger.

I'd like to have the same effects, but in my own container, myFrameLayout. But when I apply the same MyView to a FrameLayout from my main.xml (omitting findViewById and all),

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mV = new MyView(this);
    ((ViewGroup) myFrameLayout).addView(mV);
```

It actually only uses 320 x 480 area of my whole FrameLayout, so it draws fine, but only preserves(when I lift my finger) drawing on a small piece(320 x 480) on the upper-left of myFrameLayout.

How can I make MyView scale and fill the entire size of myFrameLayout using 320 x 480 bitmap as in the SDK example?

(I know I can change 320 x 480 bitmap to appropriate resolution to fill it all, but that's not what I want.)

It's my first time asking question, so please let me know if question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

your would scale your bitmap creating. use display of displaymetrics for requesting screen width and height and take this values to bitmap creating